# Text was "null"

Tags: c#, string

I have a problem with my code.

I got the code from a tutorial and at first it worked fine, but then it stopped working and got the error code text was "null".

Here is my code:

```cs
private static void Client_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
{
    var id = e.Message.Chat.Id;
    var text = e.Message.Text;

    text = text.Split(' ')[1];      //error right here!
    switch (text)
    {
        case "now":
            var response = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Client.SendTextMessageAsync(id, response);
            break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I tried something else and got another error, maybe im one step foward?!

**System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

'''
var id = e.Message.Chat.Id;
var text = e.Message.Text ?? "";

```
        text = text.Split(' ')[1] ?? "";
        switch (text)
```

'''

Comment: please provide a more general title and description to the question, so it could be relevant to others

Comment: Okay, to what i should edit it? SOrry for broken english! Im from Germany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
var text = e.Message.Text
```

to

```
 var text = e.Message.Text ?? "";
```

then change

```
text = text.Split(' ')[1];
```

to

```
if(text.Split(' ').Length >= 2)
  text = text.Split(' ')[1];
```

Comment: i will try it out!

Comment: didn't worked :(